# Adding a Remote in XCode's project's organizer - repositories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, git

I have a GIT repository created on a local server in my network at the IP address (192.168.10.10), what is the location of this repository to put in the "Add a Remote" dialog box in XCode project's Organizer ? and my Git repository does not have username/password, should I leave the username and password fields empty in this Remote page ?

P.S. XCode version is 4.2

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to clone this repo if you get SSH set up. You should be able to

```
git remote add ssh://192.168.10.10/path/to/my/repo
```

Comment: thank you for your help, however, i do not have setup for SSH on the server, and it's kinda difficult to set it up for Windows.

Comment: bitbucket and unfuddle both support private repos. Use submodules to house public 3rd party dlls on github and link via submodules. If you need to host internally, just set up a linux server on virtualbox vm. Takes a tiny amount of resources and opens up a world of possibilities with gitolite and other things. I haven't looked back since doing that. Let me know if you need anymore help. Windows is not the best for a lot of things. Hosting Git repos is one of them. I've done it in the past with network shares but it's slow for a number of reasons.